# Unable to send mail with gmail credentials from godaddy server

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Am using asp.net and have written a smtp client to send mail out using gmail. It works fine if I use VS debugger or if I host it on my PC (localhost) while it doesn't work if hosted on godaddy server. I called their technical support to know if there could be any specific setting which I missed but they declined to share any info. Here is C# code.

```
smtp = new SmtpClient();
from = new MailAddress("xxxxxxx@gmail.com");
to = new MailAddress(ToAddr);
message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.CC.Add(CCList);
message.Subject = Subject;
message.Body = body;

smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "password");
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.Timeout = (60 * 5 * 1000);
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Send(message);
```

Tried sending gmail using port 25 and 485 as suggested but it dint work out. Look forward for your support.

Comment: Did you get any notification on your  sender gmail account that someone is trying to login to your account from unusual place?

Comment: if you have access of command prompt try first telnet to that host and port.

Comment: set smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; if it is true then how it will consider custom login details

Comment: Less secure apps already enabled. I am able to send mail from debugger and local host. Tried setting smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; it dint work.

Comment: GoDaddy has settings outside you application which needs to be set to use GMAIL SMTP. 

See the solution at https://au.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Email/sending-email-through-GMail/td-p/6195

Answer (score 0):

I was getting socket closed error even though I was using the appropriate port numbers with/without SSL. It dint work. The only work around I have right now is am using my domain email id to send out emails and it works perfectly as suggested. The link i found for the same: https://www.godaddy.com/help/send-email-using-systemnetmail-19291

Thank you for your help guys. Cheers.